# Access Website through LAN using Domain name

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web

I have created a website using Visual Studio 2010 Express and pasted it inside `C:\intpub\wwwroot\` as it is. I have Windows7 home premium with iis7. Now inside IIS Manager I converted that directory into Application named **newapp**.
Now to access this application I am using `http://localhost/newapp/` and on LAN I am using `http://ipaddress/newapp/`. It is working perfect.
I want to access this application without specifying the **IP address**  each time.
How can I able to replace the IP address with some domain name to access the website? for ex, `http://somename.com/newapp/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**note:please keep a backup copy of your existing host file before making any change**

Open notepad or similar software as administrator then navigate to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

and open the hosts file.

make entry for your ip addess as shown below

```
 102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com
```

now type in the mapped host name in your web browser

Comment: Just a note, you will need to navigate to notepad first and right click Open as Administrator otherwise you won't be able to save.

Comment: It is working perfect on same PC but for LAN it still needs to use IP address. what possibly went wrong?

Comment: @PrasadJadhav you need DNS Server in your network(LAN) for that. if you have a small number of nodes then you have to edit each nodes host file.